# jmeter tear down thread grop runs several times

Tags: jmeter, teardown

I have next test plan:

Test Plan
 - set up (1 thread 1 loop)
 - Thread Group 1 (2 threads, 2 loops)
 - Thread Group 2 (2 threads, 2 loops)
 - Thread Group 3 (2 threads, 2 loops)
 - tear down (1 thread 1 loop)

In tear down section I send an email about test results. But in some cases I get several emails instead of one. I even can receive email during script execution. I use SMPT Sampler to send email.

Why can tear down run several times?

Answer (score 1):

your tear-down very likely executed per "regular" thread-group as the Jmeter [docs suggests](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) :

**these type of threads execute after the test has finished executing its regular Thread Groups**